# JPA createNativeQuery with column name (and table name) as parameter

Tags: java, jpa, jakarta-ee

It is possible to set column name (or table name) as parameter in JPA, like :

```
   Query query = em.createNativeQuery(  "select ? , ? from ?");  
   query.setParameter(1, title); 
   query.setParameter(2, value); 
   query.setParameter(3, tableName);
```

I got an SQL exception when running such code !! 
This code is used to get data from tables generated at runtime. It and do it with String concatenation, but what about setting parameters on query?

Comment: You can not set table or column name by parameter

Comment: Why do you want to do string concatination. put the static values in the string

Comment: @Jens: Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not possible, neither in this nor in any other sensible prepared statement implementation. The whole point of bind parameters is to separate code and data and a column is an identifier, thus "code".